# How do I Create and Access PHP Object Variables

Tags: php, object, variables

OK So I figured it out :) It works how it should now thanks to your example.

```
class Test_Class { 
    public function Test_Function_1(array $Test_Array_1) {
        echo'TF1_Var_1 = '. $Test_Array_1['TF1_Var_1'] . '<br> <br>';
    }
    public function Test_Function_2($Test_Selector_2, array $Test_Array_2) {
        echo'Test_Selector_2 = '. $Test_Selector_2 . '<br>';
        echo'TF2_Var_1 = '. $Test_Array_2['TF2_Var_1'] . '<br>';
    }
}

$Test_Run = new Test_Class();
$Test_Run->Test_Function_1([ 'TF1_Var_1' => 'TF1_Val_1', 'TF1_Var_2' => 'TF1_Val_2', 'TF1_Var_3' => 'TF1_Val_3' ]);
$Test_Run->Test_Function_2('TF2_Selector_Data' , [ 'TF2_Var_1' => 'TF2_Val_1', 'TF2_Var_2' => 'TF2_Val_2', 'TF2_Var_3' => 'TF2_Val_3' ]);
```

I actually didn't realize you could pass arrays through to the function, I Have not come across an example seeing that before, so I didn't know it was possible. 
I thought you could only pass strings through with a comma separating them, so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

```
class TestClass { 
    public function test1(array $array) {
        var_dump($array);
    }
    public function test2($selector, array $array) {
        var_dump($selector, $array);
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
$test->test1([ 'TF1_Var_1' => 'TF1_Val_1', 'TF1_Var_2' => 'TF1_Val_2', 'TF1_Var_3' => 'TF1_Val_3' ]);
$test->test2("TF2_Selector", [ 'TF1_Var_1' => 'TF1_Val_1', 'TF1_Var_2' => 'TF1_Val_2', 'TF1_Var_3' => 'TF1_Val_3' ]);
```

Comment: I have read the manual, but I learn better from examples. I cant really understand PHP or any language for that matter from within the documentation. How would I access those set variables from within that function? Inside "test1" or "test2". Would I have to make the function "static" so the variables are retained inside the function?

Comment: Oh boy... do you at least understand how functional programming works? Do you have any experience with using any language what so ever?

Comment: You should probably get on udemy (i.e. https://www.udemy.com/object-oriented-php-mvc/) and watch some videos to get a better understanding of how this works. 
Anyway - when you create a `class` and `methods`, you can require `arguments` in the methods. In other words the function `test1` requires an `array` variable which is then stored in `$array`. From within `test1` you can see I'm using `var_dump($array)` which will dump the content of the `$array` variable. The same goes for the `test2` function.

Comment: To instantiate the `TestClass` in php (or in any other language) you would use `new TestClass` and that to a variable - in this case the variable is `$test`. Once you have instantiated the class you can access it's methods if they are public - i.e. `$test->test2(argument1, argument2)`. Once you do `$test->test2(argument1,argument2)` you are essentially executing the code block from that method. This is a very very fast walk-through. You should read about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) and MVC (Model View Controller)